# Wordpress Elementor Forms - Restrict Email Field to ONLY allow from company domain

Tags: forms, elementor, email-validation

This is quite a workaround - but I'm only a freelancer with this company and working within what they give me.

I am using Elementors pop-up feature to restrict people from visiting a page unless they complete the form on the pop-up. What I want to do, is add a snippet of code that says:
Only emails from from xx@xxx.com can complete the form. Ulitmialty black listing every email domain except the 2 I want.

Any help?

I've only come across code that you can type in the email email domains you wnat to blacklist, but I pretty much want to blacklist every domain except two so that's not going to be suitable lol.